# How to display only last point on highcharts and that point should travel with chart line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a area chart which is having  a dynamic point that will be added to chart.I got this [http://jsfiddle.net/rjpjwve0/](http://goo.gl/MMosuL)
but it looks like the point gets displayed first and then after a delay the chart draws back.  Now i want to display the last point which will be a  animated point and it should travel with chart without delay in rendering.

[image]

Could any one help me to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a test, and it seems to work well.

I updated the load event to add a second series, using the same `series.data[len -1]` values; then in the setInterval portion, we update that new point at each iteration.

That way, by updating the existing marker rather than destroying one marker and creating another, the animation works as desired.

Code:

```
        events: {
            load: function () {
              var series  = this.series[0],
                  len     = series.data.length;

              //-------------------------------------
              //added this part ->
              this.addSeries({
                id: 'end point',
                type: 'scatter',
                marker: {
                    enabled:true,
                  symbol:'circle',
                  radius:5,
                  fillColor:'white',
                  lineColor: 'black',
                  lineWidth:2
                },
                data: [[
                  series.data[len - 1].x,
                  series.data[len - 1].y
                ]]
              }); 
              var series2 = this.get('end point');
              //-------------------------------------

              setInterval(function () {
                var x   = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    y   = Math.random();
                    len = series.data.length;
                series.addPoint([x,y], true, true);
                //and added this line -->
                series2.data[0].update([x,y]);
              }, 1000);
            }
        }
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/a6pshutt/

Comment: Thanks briggs,
That really help me out.

Comment: Hi briggs, 

Do you have any idea about how can we add animated symbol( like light glowing effect) for that marker.

-Ranjith

Comment: @Ranjith for that, I think your options would probably be to either use an animated .gif as a marker, or edit the highcharts animation code to use the built in halo (or other style) effect.

Comment: @Briggs: Thanks, will try the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        marker : {
                enabled : false,
                lineWidth: 0,
                radius: 0
            },
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
```

Its works.

Greg.

Comment: Hi Greg,

Thanks for your kind reply.

You have removed marker, I need that marker at last point and also that marker should travel along with chart line. The code which i shared earlier here was not working like that. See above pic that will help you that what i am trying to explain.

-Ranjith

Comment: Oh my bad. 
Ok, I understand your probleme. 
So, its hard. Maybe possible in javascript.